# Why can't I get a be_nil test to fail in Rspec

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

In Rspec I have the following:

```
describe "triangle.parameter" do
  it "should return nil when it has 0 sides" do
    @triangle = Triangle.new({})
    @triangle.paramater.should be_nil
  end
end
```

And I have my parameter method like so:

```
def parameter
  return 4
end
```

I've tried true, false, 4, "apple" for parameter to return and nothing will fail. I also can't get it to fail with nothing in the method. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your have paramAter in your code, is it a typo only here, on stackoverflow.com, or on your machine too?

Comment: Is the spelling of `parameter` in the test a typo, or is it really lke that?

Comment: I've fixed the spelling mistake in the code.

Comment: I've rolled it back because the spelling mistake was what caused it to be nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `@triangle.paramater` instead of `@triangle.parameter`; since it doesn't know what `paramater` is, it will always be nil.

Comment: Would turning on warnings have detected that?